# Printing strings from 2D array using pointer to pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to build a program that uses dynamic allocation to build an array of strings.
After the user finishes to enter the words he wants into the array i want to print the array one word after the other. I am using pointers to pointers, however it doesn't seem to work:

```
#define SIZE 256
void paintWords(char **words, int count_words);

void main() {
    char **words = NULL;
    int flag = 1;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    int count_words = 0;
    char *curr_word;
    while (flag)
    {
        _flushall();
        printf("Enter a word:");
        gets(buffer);
        words = (char**)realloc(words,++count_words*sizeof(char*));
        curr_word = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        words[count_words - 1] = curr_word;
        printf("Do you wish to continue(0-no, 1-yes):");
        scanf("%d", &flag);
    }
    paintWords(words, count_words);
}

void paintWords(char **words, int count_words) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count_words; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main` ouch....

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `buffer` to your `malloc`'ed block with `strcpy`

   ```
   strcpy(curr_word, buffer);
   ```

   you are discarding the read word since you don't put it anywhere
2. Don't use `gets` use `fgets` instead

   ```
   fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
   ```

   this would prevent a buffer overflow.
3. This is just the `j`st which in your case is the `0`th character of the word

   ```
   printf("%s\n", words[i][j]);
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   printf("%s\n", words[i]);
   ```

   turn compiler warnings on, it would tell you about `printf` expecting a `char *` and recieving `char` instead.

Also consider the following:

1. `main()` should return `int`.
2. You don't need to cast `malloc`.
3. Don't overwrite your pointer with `realloc`, use a temporary pointer and assign it to `array` on success only. Otherwise if `realloc` returns `NULL` you will not be able to `free(array)` for example.

Comment: The given code is not even compiling... Also we should use `free`

Comment: Your strcpy() is wrong fix it. word is a double pointer the pointer is word[idx]

Answer (score 0):

```
++count_words
words = realloc(words,count_words*sizeof(char*));
words[count_words-1] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);

strcpy(words[count_words-1],buffer);
```

Later print the array

```
printf("%s\n",words[i]);
```

`realloc()` can fail so

```
char *temp = realloc(words,count_words*sizeof(char*));

if(temp != NULL)
words = temp;
```

Few other fixes will be

You shouldn't be using `gets` which is no more a standard. Use `fgets()` and note that `fgets()` comes with a newline character

Check the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 256
void paintWords(char **words, int count_words);

void main() {
    char **words = NULL,ch;
    int flag = 1;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    int count_words = 0;
    //char *curr_word;
    while (flag)
    {

        printf("Enter a word:");
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);

        words = (char**)realloc(words,++count_words*sizeof(char*));

        words[count_words - 1] = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(words[count_words-1],buffer);
        printf("Do you wish to continue(0-no, 1-yes):");
        scanf("%d", &flag);
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n');
    }
    paintWords(words, count_words);
}

void paintWords(char **words, int count_words) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < count_words; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", words[i]);
    }
}
```